# Salesforce Custom tab which will refer to particular website

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I would like to ask for some help with apex coding. It occurred that it would be really useful to do the custom tab which would refer to the particular URL. Now we have it as a custom link but it would be much nicer if this custom link is actually as a tab - so all the process of "clicking" would remain in the tabs line.

However, to do this it is needed to do some apex coding (which I am not experienced with). Could anyone help me with the code which will lead to the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your clarification i guess you need a redirection on you visualforce page you have many ways to reach this one of them would be put this script in your page.

```
<apex:page standardController="DummyObject__c">
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.location = "http://www.salesforce.com/xxx/example/"
</script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Hello @Moti Korets. Not really. I want to put the link which I have. So I want the user to see the tab XXX and if they click on this tab it will lead them to www.salesforce.com/xxx/example/

Comment: Hi Moti, I didn't see that you changed your answer. I am sorry for the silly question but I am new to scripting in Salesforce. Could you please let me know where exactly Java script should be placed? I assume it has to be somewhere in Setup -> App Setup -> Develop. Could you please guide me through?

Comment: First create a VisualForce page in Setup -> Develop -> Page put the javascript in. For connecting a tab to this page you need to make it default controller to some object and then connect new tab to this objecy. I'll edit my answer again.